# symfony 6.2 using api-platform dynamic routes work @localhost but not when deployed on AWS using elastic beanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, symfony, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, api-platform.com

Using symfony 6.2 with api-platform/core and successfully created several dynamic routes based on #[ApiResources] annotations on Entity classes.  The localhost environment (mac) http://localhost:8001/api/docs successfully displays the docs and all the endpoints work; However, when deployed to an AWS instance the /api routes all get a 404 error.  When I set the document root to /public I do successfully get the default symfony web page.

The AWS deployment:

- Platform & Solution Stack Name: PHP 8.1 AL2 version 3.5.2
  (64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.5.2 running PHP 8.1)
- Language: PHP 8.1.13
- Composer: 2.3.5
- Proxy Server: nginx 1.22.0

The config/packages and config/routes where not altered from the initial composer generated install

app/config/routes/api_plaform.yaml

```
api_platform:
    resource: .
    type: api_platform
    prefix: /api
```

app/config/routes.yaml

```
controllers:
    resource:
        path: ../src/Controller/
        namespace: App\Controller
    type: attribute
```

Each Entity.php class has this kind of #[ApiResource] Annotation:

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ProjectRepository::class)]
#[ORM\EntityListeners(['App\EventListener\ProjectChangedNotifier'])]
#[ApiResource(
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['read']],
    denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['write']]
)]
class Project
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;
...
```

Any ideas on how to debug the routes on the AWS instance?

Comment: can you provide more information about what kind of instance are you using? also the type of stack in the AWS instance? also the apache/nginx configuration, version of php installed in your local machine vs aws intance

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my issue is realizing the AWS default elastic beanstalk php.conf does not provide a location definition needed by a symfony app when using api-platform.  I solved the issue by providing my own nginx config file that does provides for the proper locations:

```
#/etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/php.conf


location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|webp|jpe?g|png|svg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|mp4)$ {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    access_log off;
    expires 1y;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

location ~ ^/index.php(/|$) {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;

    internal;
}
```

AWS elastic beanstalk provides a [mechanism](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) to update this file using the .platform folder in your develop directory.

Checkout this excellent [github](https://github.com/alexander-schranz/AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk-PHP-Symfony-Example) example by [Alexander Schranz](https://github.com/alexander-schranz) of the elastic beanstalk .ebextentions and .platform for a symfony app.  It provides for the proper nginx configuration and also several useful deployment scripts needed by most symfony apps.